# How to ask SQL questions with table definitions and example code?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, database, sql

I am always struggling when asking SQL questions. How are we supposed to ask questions related to SQL including table definitions and code examples? Is there a jsfiddle.net equivalent for sql that works for this matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a site http://sqlfiddle.com/ which is equivalent for SQL. But don't just add its link. You should add table structure and your present code. If you want to format your table you can use this tool: [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html).

Comment: +1 And one other point to the OP. Don't forget to tag the RDBMS and version.

Comment: OMG I love that Format text tool !

Comment: It's worth pointing out that SQL Fiddle has a "Markdown Output" option for returning your queries.  This was built with the intention of making it easier to post the full details onto SO questions.  Just use the little dropdown arrow next to the "Run SQL" button to use it.